# Should drive names be constant?

Tags: 14.04, sata, hotplug

I am hot plugging two hard drives into 5 SATA controllers. And each time I see them as `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdc`.

Why?

How will I configure RAID host swap if drives can change names depending on plug order?

**UPDATE**

Here http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-creating-software-raid-one-arrays/ it is said, that to create RAID, one should issue a command like

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1
```

and in config file `/etc/mdadm.conf` one should write

```
ARRAY /dev/md0 devices=/dev/sdc1,/dev/sdd1 level=1 num-devices=2 auto=yes
```

Suppose one of drives was fail, say `/dev/sdc1`, I unplug it and then plugged back and it become `/dev/sdd1`. Configuration will become wrong.

So, no any `RAID` can fulfill it's purpose if drives referred to by logical names, right? And ergo all RAID examples over the Net are just wrong, right?

Comment: The assignment of logical device names is an implementation detail of the kernel. You should not rely on them across reboots or hot plugging actions. Use partition UUIDs or device IDs instead (see `/dev/disk/by-*`).

Answer (score 0):

To your second question:

Each storage drive has an UUID
([Wikipedia Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)) which stays the same until you change the partition (like changing filesystem, etc.). So you can use the uuid instead of sda1/sdc4/...

On the ubuntu site, there's a good explanation how to use uuids, how to find them out, and so on:
[Using UUID](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingUUID).

Comment: But if I use logical name, will it itselft tie to UUID?

Comment: By logical name you mean something like /dev/sda, right? If so, I did not make my point: 
You can talk to a device via /dev/sda or by using its uuid. An Example: On my laptop the first partition can be accessed by
/dev/sda2
or by
/dev/disk/by-uuid/c9e3a02e-6290-45e5-81cf-db12c63cc06b

The /dev/sd* can change, the uuid does not change.

Comment: Why then in all examples about RAID like here http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-creating-software-raid-one-arrays/ RAID parts identified by logical names? The intension of RAID is to continue work if drive fail or unplugged. How this can happen if drive may change it's name when replugged?

Comment: have a look at this post/the answer:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52321/using-uuids-with-mdadm
mdadm tracks the metadata it stores on the harddrives, not the logical device name.